# Move semantics for lvalue

Tags: c++, std, move-semantics, rvalue

I have made simple test to understand better move semantics. Output result was unexpected for me. Bellow is my test function:

```
template<class T>
void test(T&& v)
{
    v++;
}

void main()
{
    int v = 1;
    test(std::move(v));
    std::cout << "Output:" << v << std::endl;
}
```

My expectation was:
Output: 1
But real result was:
Output: 2

I thought as follows - I use std::move(v), as result I have conversion to "rvalue" and test function will work with temporal variable. Therefore the result should be Output: 1.
What is wrong in my conclusions?

Comment: void main does not conform to the c++ standard.

Comment: The name of `std::move` is badly chosen, and this is probably what confused you. It doesn't actually move anything. It just casts an lvalue to an rvalue, making it *possible* to do a move.

Answer (score 0):

`std::move` never constructs a temporary. It is a conversion to an rvalue-reference.

This reference is bound to `main::v`, then `test::v` parameter is initialized with it, and thus also bound to `main::v`.

If you want to create a temporary, use a cast:

```
test(int{v});
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand what type your template deduced, you can use the macro `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`

```
template<class T>
void test(T&& v)
{
    std::cout<< __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    v++;
}
```

Also this guys explains a lot of things about template deduction (your case at 35')

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwrXHznaYLA